# Android: SetOnclickListener for a EditText which is android:focusable="false"

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText which is android:focusable="false".
I would like to do something when this edittext is clicked by the user.

how can I do this please?

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot catch clicks for the object which is set unfocusable!!

Comment: Oh, and how to do that the user can not modifie the Edittext without the unfocusable function.

Comment: But if you want user not to modify edittext,why you are worrying for the task when he clicks on edittext."nothing" is the action that will happen when he clicks and he will get to know that your edittext is disabled.simple!!

Comment: try using editText.setEnabled(false);

Comment: @Hiral Thank you for the answer, In fact, I would like to use the EditText as a Text View and when the user click on it, that an Image is seted to visible. Nothing changes with the editText.setEnabled(false);

Comment: Then make it textview only. There won't be a problem i think.Then you will just have to listen for onClick onto that,not for preventing user from modifying it.

Comment: Yes, that can be the solution but I would like to profit from the EditText policy, backgrounf etd.

Comment: didn't my solution worked for this,i suggested in my previous comment?

Comment: Which soluton, with the TextView or with the editText.setEnabled(false);

Comment: With deleting the focusable = "false"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8117/discussion-between-hiral-and-ana)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution I find for this problem:

1. I declared my text view liek this:

   EditText
       android:id="@+id/Daily"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_below="@+id/UserInformations"
       android:editable="false"
   android:cursorVisible="false"
   android:longClickable="false"
       android:gravity="right" >
   EditText>

The most important is to declare those lines:

```
 android:editable="false"
 android:cursorVisible="false"
 android:longClickable="false"
```

And then use a simple setOnClickListener.